# Get Set vs Get Set with variable, difference?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between the following, and why would I choose the one above the other?

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }

VS

public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
private string _myProperty;
```

Comment: No difference unless you wanted to handle `OnPropertyChange` or you wanted to manipulate `_myProperty` differently in `get` or `set`. Bonus, you can also do `MyProperty { get; private set; }` to only let owning class set the property value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976031/difference-between-properties-with-get-set-and-without-get-set.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that's not the same question..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, the link shows difference in Field and Property. Here we have a question on difference in syntax of Property

Answer (score 0):

Shorter syntax --> less bugs
Use get set with variables for complex operations

Comment: Should be a comment

Comment: Please don't downvote without comment what is wrong on my answer

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted. But, I think the reason might be because you have enough credits to write a comment. The answer you have provided is not complete and is a small note. For it to be an answer, you must completely satisfy user's question. I believe there is more to it than just less bugs.